# How to enable 'Page Handling tab' in print dialog in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, printing

I've finally gotten around to setting up my printer in Arch Linux, but I've run into a problem.

Printing works just fine, except that when I go to print a document, when I look in the options in the print dialog, the *Page Handling* tab is missing.

I know that the tab exists because in my wife's Linux Mint setup, the tab is present, and she is using the exact same print driver (screenshot from her machine below):

[image]

How do I enable the *Page Handling* tab in the print dialog?

**Additional Details:**

- Printer is a network printer
- Attempting to print a PDF, but the behaviour appears to be consistent regardless of what is printed

  - Using `zathura` though the results are the same using `chromium`
- Printer driver is `Brother HL-2140 Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e`
- Not using a desktop environment: using a combination of `awesomewm` and other applications

Comment: Printing where? From what program? In what Desktop Environment? What spooling system? Is this a CUPS driver? What's supposed to be on this tab? I have `Page Setup` is that what you mean?

Comment: I've added as much information as I can; unfortunately I don't know what spooling system I am using.

Comment: I think its something missing from `gedit-print-settings` based on my reading, but I can't confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page handling is determined by the application, not the printer. If this functionality is important to you and not present in Zathura you could use a more fully-featured `.pdf` reader like Evince.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am hoping to resolve this without using `evince` if possible. [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1325521#p1325521) has lead me to believe that page scaling is provided by the application / pdf framework.

Comment: @NT3RP That is what I said: you need to install a `.pdf` reader with that functionality built into it. If you don't want `evince`, choose another that offers the same feature set.

Comment: I think I may not have been fully understood. I was suggesting that `zathura-pdf-poppler` may provide page scaling functionality (in which case, it should be possible to scale the print job as it is already installed, correct?).

Comment: I have no idea about zathura, I use apvlv (which doesn't provide it); the only reader I know does provide it is evince--but there are undoubtedly others. That, however, was not your question...